# Core-plot real-time-data for redraw plot

Tags: ios, core-plot, real-time-data

I have 4 hosting view on 1 self.view

```
self.hostView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 512.0, 352.0);
self.hostView2.frame = CGRectMake(512.0, 0.0, 512.0, 352.0);
self.hostView3.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 352.0, 512.0, 352.0);
self.hostView4.frame = CGRectMake(512.0, 352.0, 512.0, 352.0);
```

On hostingView i make plot. i have 4 arrays with some data.

```
self.arr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:36.23],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:38.44],
                nil];
self.arr2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:36.23],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:38.44],
                nil];
self.arr3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:36.23],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:38.44],
                nil];
self.arr4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:36.23],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:38.44],
                nil];
```

I use timer that call method generator

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(generator) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)generator
{
    [self.bd1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger count=arc4random()%30;
    [self.bd1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(20+count)]];
    [graph reloadData];

    [self.bd2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [self.bd2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(20+count)]];
    [graph2 reloadData];

    [self.bd3 removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [self.bd3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(20+count)]];
    [graph3 reloadData];

    [self.bd4 removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [self.bd4 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(20+count)]];
    [graph4 reloadData];
}
```

It's work 38 seconds and than freezes. What i can do for make it working fine. I need to reload data for making real-time

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for one approach. Instead of loading all of the plot data and labels on every update, tell the plots to update only the points that change. Use `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` to insert the new data points and `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` to remove any old data that you no longer need.